# Android NDK: C Handle seems to block native Callback

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, handle

My Android App using native functions to communicate with an usb-device. These native functions initiate the connection by using a Handle, i have to use chmod 777 the usb-device to be able to access it. The connection seems to initiate well with my tool.
Without chmod all callbacks work fine, but the connection can't be initiated.

I'm using these callbacks as some kind of "log".
I'veplaced them at several spots in my code,  to  catch errors and see how far its running without errors.

No matter where i place those callbacks, even before the connection is initiated, as soon as i use chmod, no callback is working any more. I can't avoid using chmod, else the app is not able to access the usb-device.

Some lines of my code follow, maybe they help.

So can a handle block every callbacks, even before its build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've threaded the initiating in one thread and the callback in a different thread.